# How do I configure Fluent NHibernate and Log4Net inside MSUnit Tests in VS2010

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, log4net

I'm trying to configure my Fluent NH app to either write the sql to the debug window or better yet to a log file from within my Unit Test project.  The problem is that so far I've only been able to get it to work by putting the following lines in the individual unit test

```
        var logconfig = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"App.config");
        if (logconfig.Exists)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(logconfig);
        }
```

I've tried to put the following in the AssemblyInfo.cs but to no avail

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

What I'd really like to see happen is my sql getting logged to the log file whenever I run ANY unit tests.

---

P.S. - currently using ShowSql() doesn't put anything in my Debug Output window either. :(

Comment: does `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch()` in the individual tests log it?

Comment: yes, per the question it does log if I pass in the logfile, but I want to be able to set it up for any tests that call NHibernate without copying that code

Comment: my question aims to the fact that maybe specifying "App.config" explicitly could be the key here, why the first method does log. if you have a basclass for all tests you can put it in their static constructor

Comment: a base test class is an ok solution, if you add it as an answer i'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used a base class with a static constructor to initialize logging with success

```
public abstract class TestsBase
{
    static TestsBase()
    {
        var logconfig = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"App.config");
        if (logconfig.Exists)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(logconfig);
        }  
    }

    // additional stuff here
}
```

Comment: this works for me, but frustrating that the 'normal' approach doesn't work with MS Unit tests, guess I need to upgrade my Testing framework.

Comment: for me a testing framework that needs to be installed and needs a lot of config to work is suspicous from the get go.